# ""No matter how good a life we try to live..." or "However good a life we try to live ...." or "How much ever a good life we try to live...."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, clauses

Suppose, we want to say that everyone will face some kind of suffering in life and there is no avoiding - unfortunately. And even if you try hard to avoid it, you won't be able to escape suffering. So, the following sentences seemed to be possible alternatives:

1-**How much ever a good life we try to live, we will face suffering.**

2-**However good a life we try to live, we will face suffering.**

3-**No matter how good a life we try to live, we will face suffering.**

I think number **2** and **3** are idiomatic almost and correct in grammer, but I am not quite sure about number 1- **"How much ever a good life...."** being idiomatic or grammatically correct?

Comment: 1 is wrong ('how much ever' is not correct English) 2 and 3 are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (1) How much ever a good life we try to live, we will face suffering. [image: Red X, showing invalid or incorrect form]

Sentence (1) is incorrect. "-How much ever *" is simply not grammatically valid, although the seemingly similar "*However much*" is.

> - (2) However good a life we try to live, we will face suffering. [image: Green check-mark. indicting a valid form]

> - (3) No matter how good a life we try to live, we will face suffering.  [image: Green check-mark. indicting a valid form]

Sentences (2) and (3) are both valid, and have essentially the same meaning. But that meaning is not the one suggested by the question. In this context, "*a good life*" is highly likely to be understood as "a virtuous life" not as "a life free of suffering". To express the meaning discussed in the question, one might say something like one of:

> - (3a) No matter how safe a life we try to live, we will face suffering.

> - (3b) No matter how pleasant a life we try to live, we will face suffering.